# Extract all words that match from a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract given words from string using regex:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(ur'(今天|不错)', re.UNICODE)
>>> print pattern.search(u'今天天气不错').groups()
(u'\u4eca\u5929',)
```

as you can see, only the first word is matched, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
>>> print pattern.findall(u'今天天气不错')
[u'\u4eca\u5929', u'\u4e0d\u9519']
```

The `findall()` will return all the matches of the pattern in the string.

Where as the [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) will only return the first match in the string:

> Scan through string **looking for the first location** where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance.